# How can I make these hexagons smaller?

Tags: css

Here is my dev page: http://dev.kpixel.net/honeyprovidore/

Here's the code I'm working off: http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/HhCyd

```
#categories li{
  position:relative;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:27.85714285714286%; /* = (100-2.5) / 3.5 */
  padding-bottom: 32.16760145166612%; /* =  width /0.866 */
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  visibility:hidden;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}
```

I don't understand what the original person did to get the hexagons to their size. What do I need to do to make them smaller?

Comment: adjust this, but be carefull if minimize the height and see the a part is cut, you'll have to sort it out: #categories li img{
  left:-100%; right:-100%;
  width: auto; height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;   
}

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little by guessing but it does scale it. Just change the 27.8571% to whatever you feel like is your size, for example, 10%, then do the math = 10 (your size) / 0.866 and set your padding-bottom to the result which is 11.5473%.

This should make it.

You may have some trouble placing them!

Answer (score 0):

I found an updated version of the original author's code, with media queries, which seems to work better.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #categories li{
    width:39.4%; /* = (100-1.5) / 2.5 */
    padding-bottom: 45.496%; /* =  width /0.866 */
  }
```

http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/azexKZ